# Why two oposit queries returns me the same data?

Tags: sqlite

Those queries:

```
SELECT * FROM eloquaActual as ea 
WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM eloquaActual as eff 
WHERE (eff.Email_Address != ea.Email_Address))
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM eloquaActual as ea 
WHERE exists (SELECT * FROM eloquaActual as eff 
WHERE (eff.Email_Address = ea.Email_Address))
```

Returns me exactly the same data. Also note that when I was importing data to sqlite and email address column was unique it showed me error. That I am trying to import not unique emails. Then I was trying to find any duplicates in email column. It returned me all data when I executed queries which are stated above. That means all the rows are duplicates.

BUT then I did selection where email address=any email and found just 1 record ... wtf?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "eloquaActual" ("Email_Address" VARCHAR, "Prizes_Oddset_7" VARCHAR)
```

before I had `Email_Address` unique but the error occured.

Comment: Show us structure and content of your table.

Comment: How many rows in the table, and how many distinct email addresses do you have? It is enough if you answer "at least 2" in both of these, I don't need the actual numbers.

Comment: all of the email addresses should be different and unique and rows there are 580 000 +-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exists (SELECT * FROM eloquaActual as eff 
        WHERE (eff.Email_Address != ea.Email_Address))
```

This checks whether there is *any* e-mail that is different from the current row's e-mail in `ea`.
This will happen if the table contains at least two e-mails.

```
exists (SELECT * FROM eloquaActual as eff 
        WHERE (eff.Email_Address = ea.Email_Address))
```

This checks whether there is *any* e-mail that is the same as the current row's e-mail.
This will always happen, because the row will match itself.

---

To find duplicates, you could check for some row with the *same* e-mail but a *different* ID:

```
SELECT *
FROM eloquaActual AS ea
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM eloquaActual AS eff
              WHERE eff.Email_Address = ea.Email_Address
                AND eff.rowid != ea.rowid)
```

Using GROUP BY would be easier:

```
SELECT Email_Address,
       COUNT(*)
FROM eloquaActual
GROUP BY Email_Address
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: This make sense, thank you, but what if I don't have any ID? The one thing which should be unique is email and it obviously isn't and I must find which of them aren't unique.